# Can't compile tex when using localized babel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: texlive, babel, ubuntu

I installed `texlive-full` on Ubuntu 16.04 and TeXstudio. All packages work fine except the babel. When I put `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` the file won't compile. I still can set encoding to UTF8 and properly compile file wit all special characters, however I can't with babel.

Simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \author{Jan Novák}
    \title{Příliš žluťoučký kůň}
    \maketitle
\end{document}`
```

When I compile the file It will be loading for a time. The it says *"The logfile is very large (3.09 MB) are you sure you want to load it?"*. I say yes and the logile loads. The logile is long, so I will put a link to it:

http://pastebin.com/dad8c7Zz

I don't know what else to do. I installed again `texlive-lang-czechslovak` and `texlive-lang-european` but it doesn't help. Though it was included in `texlive-full`.

The directory `csh-babel` includes this files:

```
babel.def  czech.ldf  czech.sty  hyphen.cfg  switch.def
```

The language of Ubuntu is set to English, if it changes something.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is it doing with the stuff loaded from your home directory? That looks strange to me.

Comment: And welcome btw and thanks for the log, that is helpful

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but it seems like some kind of loop until it crashes. All I did was to install texlive and editor. As I said, when I change the language to Enlish it works. However no other languages work (that I tried).

Comment: Try renaming that dot folder in your home directory, just to see if it helps. Might be bad left overs. Also the Ubuntu texlive may behave strangely if you try to use tlmgr.

Comment: What is this csh-latex directory you mention?

Comment: I've passed this on to someone which knowledge of this language, but I'm still guessing installation issues.

Comment: Sorry for delay. The `csh-latex` is misspelled `csh-babel` which is in logfile. I cant open it now for some reason. When I tried to restart computer It shows new error: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=6136233]. \LdfInit". It didnt show this one before. It says its one line 51 in file `czech.ldf` where is `\LdfInit\CurrentOption{date\CurrentOption}` placed.

Comment: When I first installed texlive I had similiar problem. I tought It was because I did not installed `texlive-full`, but `texlive` and `texlive-extra` (and maybe else). So I purged it and installed `texlive-full`.

Comment: That ldf should not be in your home directory (IMO), that looks strange. Am trying to test with a clean 16.04 vm. Will take a while

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! The logfile is now a bit different. The loop with (800+ lines of that directory csh-babel) is still there, but it now says that I am out of TeX capacity, specifically `6136233 string characters out of 6136233`. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Mind putting that log on pastebin? That mwe should not give errors.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/0E9yxghC

Comment: I've now got my hands on a fresh LUbuntu 16.04 LTS installation. Installed `texlive-full` and compiled your example (making sure it was saved as UTF8). As expected it compiles just fine and uses or produces no extra in my home dir. For example it is using this `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-czech/czech.ldf`. Compiles just fine using pdflatex, xelatx and lualatex. So my guess is a bad setup (somehow, no idea where) and is wondering a lot about that `/home/jan/.texmf-var/` stuff. I'd rename that hidden folder and recompile to see what happens.

Comment: It WORKS! I renamed the folder and it works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the log provided there are some files in the user's home directory that are being used instead of the system one. Presumably these local files are older than the system files and thus causes the errors.

Simply renaming this local (unnecessary?) folder may solve the issue.

---

Since the Ubuntu version of tlmgr (the texlive manager) is different from upstream tlmgr, in that it installs things in the local users home dir, which causes problems if you later update your latex installation (or linux), my guess is that the OPs at some point have been running the Ubuntu tlmgr

I generally recommend installing the upstream TL to avoid this kind of confusion.